# How to reset the 'role settings' in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

After customizing the role settings (changed the 'public' role, just tick everything to Deny, then I set it back), all of my users cannot login, except to give them the sysadmin permission. So, I want to reset the role settings, is there any way to do that?

Comment: Define "customizing the role settings".  What are they doing that needs sysadmin?!

Comment: @OMG Ponies, I just added the definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the database level, you'd drop and recreate the user

At the server level: un-deny everyone or drop/recreate logins

You can also use something like to create another query to fix everything

```
SELECT
    'REVOKE DENY ' + name + 'Stuff'
FROM
    sys.server_principals
...
```

However, I've never managed to lock all my users out like this so you'll have to play with this query to get it to do what you want.